# Broken autocomplete/intellisense in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: autocomplete, intellisense

so for the past ~1wk now my autocomplete/intellisense is BROKEN in most of my project. I've found the occasional file that somehow magically has autocomplete, etc. This is severely hindering my workflow and I've been back and forth with the (incompetent) support technicians for visual studio. Has anyone experienced the same issue/could give some insight on why this might happen?

This is confirmed only happening on my main project. All others I try to open are fine..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation recently. My problem was custom targets failing in the intellisense builds that weren't failing in the context of the whole build. (They were like compiling typescript or other things not necessary for the VS experience.) Anyway, the fix for me was to add a `Condition="'$(DesignTimeBuild)' != 'true'"` to each of those targets so they wouldn't get run for design-time builds.

The way I found it might be useful to you:

1. Installed MSBuild Binary and Structured Log Viewer (https://msbuildlog.com/)
2. Installed Project System Tools extension for VS (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProjectSystemTools)
3. Start logging builds (by clicking the play button):
   [image: In the Build Logging pane from the VS extension, click play to start logging builds]
4. Trigger a Clean on your project and look for any DesignTimeBuilds that are failing (this was actually what was breaking my intellisense) and open them in the tool from step 1.
   [image: Use "Open Logs External..." to pop them into the structured log viewer from step 1]
5. Fix build breaks.
6. Get back to intellisense goodness.